# setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to create a jquery fadeto type of effect in Javascript, but am having an issue with my setTimeout command.

Here is the code:

```
function textfade(y) {
    var x = document.getElementById("test");
    var y;           
    if (y == undefined) {
        y = 1.0;
    } 

    x.style.opacity = y;
    y -=0.1;
    setTimeout(function(){ textfade(y); }, 50);
}
```

The problem is `x.style.opacity = y`.

Without that, the timeout runs fine. With it, however, it runs through the function one time and then dies. While I feel like it's a simple error, I am out of ideas for fixing it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdmJt/).

Comment: It works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/3yDMP/ Possibly you are calling it before dom is ready?

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem, but consider adding a terminating condition (`if (y === 0)`).

Comment: Get rid of the `var y;` line and it'll be fine

Comment: You're both accepting `y` as an argument and declaring a local variable called `y`. Probably want to do one or the other.

Comment: I think its happening to fast for you to notice. Remember 50 is 50 milliseconds. http://jsfiddle.net/43t5j/ works fine if you slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are running it after `test` element is already available. Here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3yDMP/ . And here: http://jsfiddle.net/3yDMP/3/ - no  , because function is called in head, not in onload (like in first fiddle), when dom is not ready yet and is not available.

So, in your could be

```
<head>
  <script>
       function textfade() {...}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="textfade()">
    <div id="test"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! That got it to work. Do I feel foolish now. Let's just attribute it to me spending so much time on this tiny animation that my eyes are melting out of my skull. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're re-declaring `y` each time `textfade()` is executed, effectively destroying / resetting the passed parameter.

Remove:

```
var y;
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this would be better with the `setTimeout` calling an internal closure where the current opacity level is maintained outside of the fade function itself, so you don't have to pass it around.

```
function textfade(el) {
    if (typeof el === "string") {
        el = document.getElementById(el);
    }

    var opacity = 1.0;

    (function fade() {
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        opacity -= 0.1;
        if (opacity > 0) {
             setTimeout(fade, 50);
        }
    })();
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/TQHYj/

Comment: You realize in IE8 and lower you're creating two completely distinct `fade` functions, right? http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html

Comment: damned b0rked browsers...  Ideally I would use an anonymous function and `arguments.callee` in the `setTimeout` call, but ECMA in their wisdom have deprecated `arguments.callee` :sigh:

Comment: You just have to use an anonymous function: `var fade = function() {…}; fade();` or `function fade() {…} fade();`

Comment: @JulienRoyer I prefer to avoid the external call to `fade` and use IIFE's.

Comment: @Alnitak: so do I, but you sometimes have to be pragmatic…

Comment: @Alnitak: :-) Good news is that IE9 and all other modern browsers do it right, and it's *frequently* harmless anyway. Just declare `fade` (doesn't have to be anonymous) and then call it after the declaration. Clearer anyway (I know, subjective).